# What are these equations called in English?

Tags: terminology, mathematics

I just wonder what these simple equations are called in English? Do they have professional names/terminologies in math?

> equation 1: x = a + b - c

> equation 2: x = a * b / c

The key is the sign, equation 1 only contains plus and/or minus signs. Equation 2 contains only Multiplication and division signs. a, b, and c are variables, they could be a complex term, or a single known or unknown value.

So, what do I call these two types of equations in English? I know the first one might be called a linear equation, but how about the second one?

Comment: The second type used to be known as "quadratic equations" when I was at school - but that was a very long time ago! The first type looks like a *simple equation* - though if there really are four unknowns, you are way beyond me.

Comment: Have you checked the bilingual dictionary?

Comment: @WS2 a quadratic equation is one where a  term is squared (multiplied by itself). The term derives from the latin quadratus (made square). The second equation is not a quadratic equation, because no term is multiplied by itstelf. Both are linear equations https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/linear-equations/

Comment: @JavaLatte Apologies - it's been a long time!

Comment: @javalatte the second equation is also a linear equation?

Comment: @Elizabeth The second is not linear.  Technically neither is the first (because a, b or c could be complex non-linear terms. See my updated answer.

Comment: It matters whether the symbols _x_, _a_, _b_ and _c_ are indeterminate (are to be treated as variables) or not.  Without knowing, the reasonable thing is to treat _a_, _b_, and _c_ as _variables_.  To say they're not important, to offer what they could be, and to imply that they could be a "known or unknown value" does not add a well-defined constraint your question.  Just say whether they are _variables_ or _constants_.

Comment: @Wyck thank you for your comment. x,a,b,c are variables, not constant for sure. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the expressions on the right-hand-side of the two formulae:

The first expression is a *sum* of three *terms*: a, b and -c.

Longer sums (especially when written with Σ notation) are also called *series*.

The second expression is *product* of three *factors* a, b and c<sup>-1</sup>

*What about "linear equations"*.  Well this is maths, not English learning.  An equation is linear if it is in the form **y** = A **x** (where "A" is a constant (possibly a matrix), and x and y are (possibly vector) variables), or in some contexts if y=ax + b.
However you say that a, b, c "could be a complex term, or a single known or unknown value."  and so these equations are not in general linear.

If you consider x,a,b and c all to be variables, then  "x = a+b+c" is *linear* (it could be written in matrix form x = (1 1 1)(a b c)<sup>T</sup>) The second is not linear, or *non-linear*.

Comment: thank you so much! Clearly, the question is more complicated than I thought. Yes, I'll go for 'linear' and 'non-linear' with some extra explanation about the formulas.

Answer (score 3):

The expression on the right-hand side of the first equation (a + b - c) is a "trinomial", and the expression on the right-hand side of the second (a * b / c) is a "monomial". (You could therefore call the equations a "trinomial equation" and a "monomial equation", but those expressions aren't very common.)

The equations can also be classified according to their degree, and I think that some people have gotten confused because you don't specify what a, b, and c are.

- If all three letters are constants, then both equations are constant.
- If either a or b is a variable (and the other two letters are constants), then both equations are linear.
- If at least two of those letters are variables, then the first equation is linear but the second isn't.

Answer (score 1):

These are **arithmetic expressions** and you could say *arithmetic equations* or *arithmetical equations* if you needed to insist that they are equations.

The first example is in [Presburger_arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) and the second in Peano arithmetic, which are theories of the natural numbers, but both are highly technical and wouldn't be understood by a general audience

Comment: This answer assumes that these are assignment in a computer language, but the OP mentions maths, the reference to Presburger and Peano arithmetic is confusing and incorrect.  There is no suggestion or requirement that a, b, c represent natural numbers.  Peano arithmetic has no "division" operation. There is no technical nor colloquial context in which you would say "a * b / c is an expression in Peano arithmetic"

Comment: In mathematics, there is a distinct difference between **equation** and **expression** and the two terms cannot be used interchangeably.  An **equation** has an equals sign, an **expression** does not.